# React component returns blank page on App.js

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to get my component in react display from App.js
It does not work ,does not even show the components, just shows a blank page.

I am getting confused as to why its not showing.

My code is looking like this :

## mainReg

```
import React from 'react';

const mainReg = () =>{
    return(
        <div>
            <h2>Hey react!</h2>
        </div>
    );
}

export default mainReg;
```

## app.js

```
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';
import mainReg from './mainReg';


function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <mainReg/>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Why does it return a blank page?

Comment: Try capitalizing the first letter, `MainReg` instead of `mainReg` everywhere

Comment: Yes, I guess it is because of the capitalize name.

Comment: @Akshay, thanks fam. Learnt this one. The capitalization solved the problem.

Comment: It must to use capitalize when declaring the `Class`

Answer (score 0):

```
import React from 'react';

const MainReg = () =>{
    return(
        <div>
            <h2>Hey react!</h2>
        </div>
    );
}
export default MainReg;
```

App.js

```
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';
import MainReg from './mainReg';


function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <MainReg/>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```